# Pesquisar dentro de csv e trazer outras colunas da linha - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Bom tenho um aplicação em Python que gera um arquivo csv de 7000 linhas e 4 colunas, por exemplo:

```
Mesa,Entrada,Saida,Conta
"P",21:00,22:00,95.00
"A",14:00,18:00,195.00
"C",18:00,21:00,75.00
"D",16:30,18:30,75.00
"E",16:00,18:45,178.00
"R",19:00,15:45,178.00
"Z",19:00,15:45,178.00
```

Basicamente a aplicação tem que pesquisar pela Mesa "X" e como resultado trazer a conta da mesa "X". Atualmente faço assim:

```
def get_status(mesa):
    csv_loc = f"{os.getcwd()}/teste.csv"
    with open(csv_loc) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(readCSV, None)
        for row in readCSV:
            if row[0] == mesa:
                return row[3]
```

Mas queria fazer de outra maneira com pandas por exemplo, alguém conhece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a biblioteca pandas é bem simples resolver esse problema. Você pode ler o csv automaticamente usando comando read_csv do pandas. E filtrar as linhas que contém a mesa que você quer. No meu exemplo abaixo, eu filtrei quais linhas tem a coluna Mesa igual a "P". `df[df.Mesa=="P"]`. Você pode fazer esse tipo de operação lógica com qualquer coluna.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("teste.csv")
mesa_p = df[df.Mesa=="P"]
print(mesa_p)
```

Se você quiser trabalhar com arrays do python normal mesmo, você pode converter o resultado para uma matrix, assim como no código abaixo.

```
mesa_p = mesa_p.as_matrix()
print(mesa_p[0]) # Escrever no ecrã a primeira linha da matrix.
```

Comment: Cara valeu era isso mesmo que estava procurando, a unica alteração que fiz foi: print(mesa_p[0][3]), para trazer o campo conta

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! :)